# How to import variables from an external twig file?

Tags: php, twig

In different pages' templates I use the same fields array, so I decided to set it in one file, and then include this file into my templates:

base_fields.twig

```
{% set base_fields = ["id", "name", "description", "priority"] %}
```

index.html.twig

```
{% extends '@App/Default/layout.html.twig' %}
{% block base_fields %}
    {% include '@App/task_abstract/base_fields.twig' with vars %}
{% endblock %}
```

But I get "Variable "base_fields" does not exist."

Why it isn't working and how to implement my idea?

Comment: Have you tried `use` instead of `include`? https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/use.html

Comment: Can't be done that way. Included files have their own scope for variables

Comment: Yep, 'use' gives the same result.

Comment: You shouldn't readily be setting variables in twig at all. Best practice is to set them in your controller.